# Facing problem for accessing nested element by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have few nested table with in datalist like

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlList" runat="server" Width="50%"
        onitemdatabound="dlList_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table border="0px" id="tblOuter" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table id="tblInner" border="0px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr class="AccordionPanelTab">
                                <td class="QSHeader"><asp:Label ID="lblHead" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("QA") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                <td align="right"><asp:Image ID="toggleImg" CssClass="ToggleImageStyle" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/up-arrow.png" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr >
                    <td class="AccordionPanelContent"><div  id="content" runat="server" style="padding-left : 10px"></div></td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

so i was trying to access element when click on tr having class called "AccordionPanelTab".

i wrote a jquery to access element like `<div  id="content">`

```
<asp:Image ID="toggleImg" CssClass="ToggleImageStyle" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/up-arrow.png" /> when user click on tr having class called "AccordionPanelTab".
```

my jquery is

---

this is not my actual jquery. here i am doing few trial & error for accessing element.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("tr.AccordionPanelTab").click(function () {
            alert($(this).parent().parent().attr("id"));
            alert($(this).parent().parent().closest("table").attr("id"));

        });
     })
```

but i am not being able to do so........anyone can help. thanks

Comment: Which `<table>` _id_ do you want; inner or outer?

Comment: when a user clicks a `<td>` with class `AccordionPanelContent`, you would like to alert the id of the table in which the clicked row is contained? Is that what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: You should know by now how to format code properly after 288 questions..

Comment: when user click on tr having class called "AccordionPanelTab" then i need to access toggleImg image client ID and <div  id="content"> content client id which is in another TR of outer table.... which i need to pass to other function. so please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr.AccordionPanelTab").live('click', function () {
        var imageID = $(this).find("img.ToggleImageStyle").attr("id");
        var contentID = $(this).closest("table").parent().parent().next().find("td.AccordionPanelContent div").attr("id");
        //alert("Image ID: " + imageID);
        //alert("Content ID: " + contentID);
    });
});
```

On an unrelated side note, please refrain from using `id="tblOuter"` and `id="tblInner"` inside the Data Presentation Control as it generates invalid HTML. ID should be used only once in an HTML document. Either use `runat="server"` or change it to `class`

Comment: when user click on tr having class called "AccordionPanelTab" then i need to access toggleImg image client ID and <div  id="content"> content client id which is in another TR of outer table.... which i need to pass to other function. so please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("tr.AccordionPanelTab").click(function () {

            alert($(this).closest("table").attr("id"));

        });
     });
```

[`jquery closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: when user click on tr having class called "AccordionPanelTab" then i need to access toggleImg image client ID and <div  id="content"> content client id which is in another TR of outer table.... which i need to pass to other function. so please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To access the `tblInner` and `tblOuter` tables:

```
var oDirectParent = $(this).parents("table");
var oGrandParentTable = oDirectParent.parents("table");
```

The `.parent()` method returns the direct parent node, for `<tr>` this will be the `<tbody>`.

Comment: when user click on tr having class called "AccordionPanelTab" then i need to access toggleImg image client ID and <div  id="content"> content client id which is in another TR of outer table.... which i need to pass to other function. so please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You only want to look up elements by *id*? Then it doesn't matter *where* they are; JavaScript can just get the element by it's `id` attribute.

```
$('tr.AccordionPanelTab').click(function(){
    var content = $('#content');
    var toggleImg = $('#toggleImg');
});
```

Now let's hope your `id`s are unique in the page. If not you'll need to fix that and I'll need to provide a new solution.